# Discord.ext.menus is not able to be imported because of an "Unknown location"

Tags: python, discord.py

When importing the python lib discord-ext-menus, found at: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus, I get given an error of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vahin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 934, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\vahin\PycharmProjects\MyDiscordBot v2.0\My-Discord-Bot\cogs\Help.py", line 5, in <module>
    from discord.ext import menus
ImportError: cannot import name 'menus' from 'discord.ext' (unknown location)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vahin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vahin\PycharmProjects\MyDiscordBot v2.0\My-Discord-Bot\BotMain.py", line 27, in on_ready
    await bot.load_extension(i)
  File "C:\Users\vahin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1012, in load_extension
    await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\vahin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 937, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.Help' raised an error: ImportError: cannot import name 'menus' from 'discord.ext' (unknown location)
```

I have tried reinstalling the library multiple times - but nothing has happened.

Answer (score 0):

discord.ext.menus is not installed with discord.py. To install it you need to run `python -m pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus` in your virtual enviroment

Comment: I already tried running that multiple times - in my questions I stated that "I have tried reinstalling the library multiple times - but nothing has happened."